# Setting Cache-Control header, AWS S3 presigned URL image upload from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to work with AWS PHP SDK using PostObjectV4 to upload image from clients browser.

```
        $client = new S3Client([        
            'version' => 'latest',          
            'region' => 'us-east-2',        
            'credentials' => [ 
                  'key' => S3_KEY,         
                  'secret' => S3_SECRET,   
            ]
        ]);                    
        $bucket = 'bucketsomewhere.coim';  

        $formInputs = ['acl' => 'public-read'];

        $options = [           
            ['acl' => 'public-read'],       
            ['bucket' => $bucket],          
            ['starts-with', '$key', 'Users/'],
            ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'image/'],
            ['starts-with', '$Cache-Control', 'max-age='],
        ];

        $expires = '+40 minutes';       

        $postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4(
            $client,
            $bucket,
            $formInputs,
            $options,
            $expires
        );
```

After sending POST request from JS. It gives me following error:
**Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000"]**

I read it about from [their docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html), but no success. Help is needed :) .

Comment: No longer needed. I forgot set 'Cache-Control' value in the request.